# Bitcoind gui client, wallet client with peer preference, node manager

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, full-node

first time user here so politely point out any thing I have done wrong.

I am looking for three things, but first let me explain the situation and use case:

- I am using bitcond full node on a headless FreeBSD OS server. There is no GUI of any kind.
- I am able to use CLI RPC (from an SSH session) to send commands to bitcoind. It works but I'm not a fan of it. I'm able to view account and wallet detail.

I would like to have working, using very secure technology/products:

- A very secure 'remote wallet' GUI client that can 'connect' to bitcoind over the IP network. Use case will be 99.999% local LAN only, but if I want to allow it via WAN/Internet I can.  I realize the risks involved doing that over the Internet, but that is what I am looking for.
- A bitcoind full node GUI manager. Please do the not confuse this with the first.  This application allows me to use a GUI to securely manage the node itself, via IP.  I'm guessing this would also be via RPC.
- A wallet manager application like Armory, but one that allows me to configure it to securely peer only with my full node. Thus when I make transactions, the transactions are securely between my local PC wallet and my node.

See what I mean? I've done lots of looking, but no luck yet. Much thanks all.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I am not aware of answers to much of your question but, think I may be able to help with one tiny section.

Answer (score 0):

yup, see what you mean. Hopefully my answer is not disappointing. It is to my knowledge not existant. I'd reason this way:
I don't think it's the application, which should secure the network layer. Vice versa is the way to go on (layered approach). Create a secure network layer, and run the app on top of it. Otherwise all apps would build their own security layer, and I doubt there are enough security specialists...

The layers of the underlying OS allows to achieve security.

> A very secure 'remote wallet' GUI:

define secure :-) Well, why not tunnel X over a VPN or through ssh?

> A bitcoind full node GUI manager:

is the same.

> A wallet manager application:

again, security built into the app is against principle of layers. You can tell your full node, from which IP to connect.

Comment: When I said "A very secure 'remote wallet' GUI" I meant a product that has international reputation ha being rock solid secure, versus a GitHub weekend project.  When I said "A bitcoind full node GUI manager" its because my bitcoind does not have a built in GUI; its CLI only.  As for "wallet manger" I understand now that is referred to as a SPV client. I found one but of course its programmers picked the servers it uses. I can't use my server.  But I will keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

> A wallet manager application like Armory, but one that allows me to configure it to securely peer only with my full node. Thus when I make transactions, the transactions are securely between my local PC wallet and my node.

If you run `bitcoind` on server 1 and on client pc 1 run `>bitcoin-qt -connect={server 1}` then client pc 1 should not try to connect to any other nodes. When you say securely, you could easily run Tor on each and specify the hidden service running on server 1. See [this Q/A](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/70069/how-can-i-setup-bitcoin-to-be-anonymous-with-tor) for information on setting up Tor.

I understand that it is now possible to run Electrum Home Server to do much of what you asked about.